# SC/OPENSC How to write and read

Tags: linux, smartcard, opensc

I'm sorting out how to achieve the following, I want to use smart or memory cards in a project. The cards should be read by standardized card readers (for example ACR38). When they are read by the computer ( command line or by a software (processing or p5js or similar), there should be a popup a window which shows the contents of the card being a picture and a text. Bit similar when I use my regular ID to be read by my E-idsoftware.

[image: https://www.pc-helpforum.be/uploads/monthly_2016_11/viewer-read-eid-ok.png.5cab04693529e36cc130dbd125c70053.png]

For the moment the card I have is this one **SLE4428** (at the bottom instructions from the vendor) 
These have no data on it yet and are bought blank

=> [datasheet](http://www.futurlec.com/Smart_Card_001.shtml)

The software I found but don't know if it's suited for my project and how to specifically use it is the following.

Opensource tools that I found when searching for SC cards software (no id how to use them.)

https://linux.die.net/man/1/opensc-tool

https://linux.die.net/man/1/opensc-explorer

I looked at my smartcard reader and found that http://www.acr38u.com/
is a platform but has to be payed for and I'm unable to found sofware for this on linux or apple. 
Again here I found a [datasheet](http://downloads.acs.com.hk/drivers/en/PMA_ACR38x%28CCID%29_v6.01.pdf) with hex code to connect to the card, but still not how to physically connect to the cards.

This site shows many points of a working shell but I can't find the installer for it. [opendsc](https://www.openscdp.org/scsh3/application.html)

Then lastly [this](http://pcsclite.alioth.debian.org/) is the most promising and I already contacted the maker of it. But installation gets stuck in the make process (which I've already searched for and is not solution yet, being at it for a week now so therefore this post, maybe the community can help with an alternative look)

This is the explanation from the vendor side (Aliexpress) which is kind of specific. Though I don't know where to input these hex codes to write or read from the card. (there is a software but it's windows (If there is somebody that can say, that the way to solve the core question of my project then I'll try to get a windows pc to work on it via that way))

```
ISO7816 SLE 4442 Chip PVC Contact Smart Card (0.8* 85.5 * 54mm)

If you need write the 4442 cards,you should buy the contact smart reader writer!! 4442 cards not support 13.56mhz rfid writer!!!
NOTE:There is NO magnetic strip behind the card.
Graphics Quality Cards For All Photo ID Card Printers Including
DataCard, Zebra, Fargo, Evolis, Magicard, NBS & etc.
(These Cards Will Not Work In Inkjet Printers)
If you need 100pcs 4442 cards,pls check the links below:
[https://www.aliexpress.com/store/product/100-pcs-lot-ISO7816-RFID-Contact-SLE-4442-Chip-PVC-Smart-Card/516120_32425491077.html?spm=2114.12010608.0.0.R0bzFx][1]


Features:
Standard:ISO7816
Product Chip:SLE4442
Color:White
Dimension: L 85.5 x W 54 x H 0.80±0.04mm
256 × 8-bit EEPROM organization
32 × 1-bit organization of protection memory
erase cycles more than 100,000 times
Data retention for minimum of ten years
Default passwords: FFFFFF
3 bytes for error counter and card secret code area
1,Write protected area (first 32 bytes) of each byte can be individually write protected, After write,the data can't be changed.
2, Before checking the password, all the data can be read, if necessary,you could encryption data.
3, After confirm password is correct,the data could be write or modify.
4, The 3 bytes of user passwords, after confirm is correct,it could be change.
5, The password error counter, the initial value of 3, check the error code 1, then subtract 1, if the counter value is 0, the card is automatically locked, the data just read out, no longer change can no longer be password verification; if zero, the one time password verification is correct, restore to the initial value.
6, The byte address 0-5,6-7 factory prior written by the manufacturers can not be changed.
```

The specifics for this question lies in either

A: How can I achieve a working environment on linux or mac (first) to read and write data on an sc card (the one I have or !B: a working alternative) 
C: Create a viewer program or webapp, etc.. to view or route the data to when the SC card is being read. (This would be a valid question, If i where to chose a Windows based existing program, I think)

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: I think you should focus on a specific programming problem and ask a targeted question. The question seems to run-on, and I stopped reading after the third paragraph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because this is not code specific, but I still want people that have the same questions to be able to see this page to show them pletora of scripts and ways to approach this or similar SC project.

This [guy](https://ludovicrousseau.blogspot.be/2014/09/pcsc-sample-in-javascript-nodejs.html) knows a lot about OpenSC!